# The sending of Geolocation co-ordinates to a Database

Tags: html, geolocation

I am creating a mobile app via phonegap and HTML5 and I currently can't find much information online about sending Geolocation to a database or if easier to local storage. I am using the simple Geolocation code plus code I found to send the varibles to a database -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
$dbLink = new mysql('localhost','','','');
    if(mysql_connect_errno()) {
        die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysql_connect_error());
    }


var x=document.getElementById("demo");
window.onload = function getLocation()
 {
if (navigator.geolocation)
 {
 navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
 }
 else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
 }
 function showPosition(position)
 {
 x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
 "<br />Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
 }
 var lat = position.coords.latitude;
 var lon = position.coords.longitude;
 {
 function showPosition(position)
 {
 coords.lat = position.coords.latitude;
 coords.lon = position.coords.longitude;

 x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + coords.lat + 
 "<br />Longitude: " + coords.lon;  



  }function sendToServer(){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO geolocation VALUES('$Latitude','$Longitude')";
  mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  mysql_free_result($sql);
  mysql_close();



 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is my attempt; I am focusing on sending it to phpmyadmin primarily.

I don’t know what way to go about it. I would normally use a form to send to a database, but I don’t know how to go about sending the info via a form. If anybody has a suggestion I'd be very happy to hear it. I thought about using geotagging but it didn’t work out and saving the page as a PDF and sending the PDF to the database but these are possible workarounds that I would rather not do.

Comment: is your problem that you do not know on how you could pass the values to the server, and you have the Database management code running in your serverside ?

Comment: phpMyAdmin isn't a database; you probably instead mean you're sending it to MySQL. But anyway, what is the error message you're getting and what is the expected result? What is an example value of `$Latitude` and `$Logitude` here? It appears to me as if you're putting PHP code in to where JavaScript belongs, which very much won't work because they're two different languages (not to mention JavaScript is run locally and your mysql_connect is attempting to connect to localhost; your MySQL database isn't on the phone though. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the code here; where did it come from?